# Powershell reading Excel date as 5 digit number

Tags: .net, excel, datetime, powershell

I have a Powershell script that uses [this PowerShell module](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920183617/http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/04/use-ace-drivers-and-powershell-to-talk-to-access-and-excel.aspx). It basically allows me to query Excel workbooks like a database. Everything looks good except it reads dates in as that wonky 5-digit date representation instead of a date.

I've checked the column formatting in the files themselves and they are formatted as MM/DD/YYYY as they should be; my script just reads them in as the 5-digit date.

Example: 2/1/10 => 40057

I need to convert 40057 to the appropriate date, either using something native to Powershell (.NET), or even a formula would set me right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number you get, is the number of days since 31/12/1899.

You can convert it by adding the number to the .Net DateTime using AddDays, or you can use [DateTime.FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx).

Sorry, I don't know the specific Powershell syntax.

[There is something strange with these days in the first two months of 1900.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html)

Comment: Will also need to know if the workbook is using 1904 date settings - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162

Comment: @HonusWagner 'This is because Excel behaves as if the date 1900-Feb-29 existed' - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

Comment: @GvS I used DateTime.FromOADate and it works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the PowerShell syntax, based on [@GvS' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8068427/238639):

```
$date = 43557
[DateTime]::FromOADate($date)
```

The output:

```
Tuesday, April 2, 2019 12:00:00 AM
```