# Reading date time form an excel file using Powershell

Tags: excel, date, powershell

I am using following code to read an excel file using powershell. There are several date columns in the excel file with format yyyy-mm-dd format. When the PowerShell reads date columns it renders a digit. How do I change this digit to a real date time.

```
$oldci = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
$newci = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]"en-US"

$path="C:\project1\Spreadsheet2.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$objExcel.visible = $false
[system.threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $newci
$objWorkbook =$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($path)  
$worksheet = $objWorkbook.sheets.item("Temp")

Write-Host $worksheet.cells.item(3, 3).value2 //here is a digit.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell reading Excel date as 5 digit number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068353/powershell-reading-excel-date-as-5-digit-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would post this into the comment section but i can't duo to reputation restriction.
Have a look at this post here: [Powershell reading Excel date as 5 digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068353/powershell-reading-excel-date-as-5-digit-number)

Answer (score -1):

The text property will return the date properly instead of value2.

Write-Host $worksheet.cells.item(3, 3).text