# How do I extract the Year from an Excel serial date number

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-5.0

If I want to convert an Excel serial date to a datetime using PowerShell I can do

`$date = 43557`

`[DateTime]::FromOADate($date)`

and the get the entire datetime, but how can I extract only the **year** from the serial date and pass it to a variable?

Comment: `[DateTime]::FromOADate($date).Year` - see [`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

You can use `[DateTime]::FromOADate($date).Year`.

You can refer to [DateTime Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) and [Powershell reading Excel date as 5 digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068353/powershell-reading-excel-date-as-5-digit-number)